# Python Flask and Optional Routing - Code Design

Tags: python, flask, routes, url-routing

i am interested to understand a few use-cases of the following code:

```
@app.route('/items', defaults={'category': 'all'})
@app.route('/items/<category>')
def get_items(category='all'):
    return f"Items in category: {category}"
```

I understand why this could be used to facilitate a fallback behavior to a specific routing, but are there any other use cases?

PS: Apologies in advance if this is not the right stack site for this. Please redirect me if necessary.